# R: How to visualize interactive time series via boxplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, ggplotly

I have monthly time series data and monthly boxplots. Now I want to visualize the same boxplot but via plotly instead of ggplot in order to make it interactive and replace numbers by months names on the x-axis

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c("January 2018", "January 2018", "January 2018", 
"February 2018", "February 2018", "February 2018", "March 2018", 
"March 2018", "March 2018", "April 2018", "April 2018", "April 2018", 
"May 2018", "May 2018", "May 2018", "June 2018", "June 2018", 
"June 2018", "July 2018", "July 2018", "July 2018", "August 2018", 
"August 2018", "August 2018", "September 2018", "September 2018", 
"September 2018", "October 2018", "October 2018", "October 2018", 
"November 2018", "November 2018", "November 2018", "December 2018", 
"December 2018", "December 2018", "January 2019", "January 2019", 
"January 2019", "February 2019", "February 2019", "February 2019", 
"March 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "April 2019", 
"April 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", "June 2019", 
"June 2019", "June 2019", "July 2019", "July 2019", "July 2019", 
"August 2019", "August 2019", "August 2019", "September 2019", 
"September 2019", "September 2019", "October 2019", "October 2019", 
"October 2019", "November 2019", "November 2019", "November 2019", 
"December 2019", "December 2019", "December 2019", "January 2020", 
"January 2020", "January 2020", "February 2020", "February 2020", 
"February 2020", "March 2020", "March 2020", "March 2020", "April 2020", 
"April 2020", "April 2020", "May 2020", "May 2020", "May 2020", 
"June 2020", "June 2020", "June 2020", "July 2020", "July 2020", 
"July 2020", "August 2020", "August 2020", "August 2020", "September 2020", 
"September 2020", "September 2020", "October 2020", "October 2020", 
"October 2020", "November 2020", "November 2020", "November 2020", 
"December 2020", "December 2020", "December 2020"), Category = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C"), Sales = c(10222332, 7942779, 725555250, 6375699, 
2875550, 440631801, 8864571, 12334681, 629036931, 7473920, 9161918, 
659864891, 10047537, 8466945, 687218719, 8980204, 9829918, 612005973, 
10301078, 8539884, 626423889, 11668052, 9367543, 652252806, 10374909, 
7755942, 543875760, 14635624, 4343942, 561692585, 13560795, 5791480, 
532812769, 12662526, 3759661, 555013915, 15786646, 3853641, 626093690, 
9505737, 5993417, 351970315, 16938873, 13168685, 600298206, 10827490, 
10334899, 723990224, 14967314, 7270579, 631821347, 14495324, 
6507689, 533818484, 13449295, 7678789, 535126612, 17214970, 5880437, 
564680477, 12970874, 4965748, 557062440, 15750730, 8085819, 600121430, 
18948080, 6057461, 592022480, 16238799, 6148273, 629364277, 12143876, 
4314784, 451238348, 5354879, 5703890, 460174095, 5430258, 5204303, 
670928810, 7591477, 7459831, 636383634, 5387797, 8551921, 535302293, 
7103341, 8104402, 518039675, 7411340, 9247334, 466740767, 7815582, 
8410930, 554147105, 9270913, 7991272, 539793655, 13351559, 8675692, 
559303077, 10258273, 6158217, 550218658, 11708049, 13333011, 
578068296)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -108L), groups = structure(list(Time = c("April 2018", 
"April 2018", "April 2018", "April 2019", "April 2019", "April 2019", 
"April 2020", "April 2020", "April 2020", "August 2018", "August 2018", 
"August 2018", "August 2019", "August 2019", "August 2019", "August 2020", 
"August 2020", "August 2020", "December 2018", "December 2018", 
"December 2018", "December 2019", "December 2019", "December 2019", 
"December 2020", "December 2020", "December 2020", "February 2018", 
"February 2018", "February 2018", "February 2019", "February 2019", 
"February 2019", "February 2020", "February 2020", "February 2020", 
"January 2018", "January 2018", "January 2018", "January 2019", 
"January 2019", "January 2019", "January 2020", "January 2020", 
"January 2020", "July 2018", "July 2018", "July 2018", "July 2019", 
"July 2019", "July 2019", "July 2020", "July 2020", "July 2020", 
"June 2018", "June 2018", "June 2018", "June 2019", "June 2019", 
"June 2019", "June 2020", "June 2020", "June 2020", "March 2018", 
"March 2018", "March 2018", "March 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", 
"March 2020", "March 2020", "March 2020", "May 2018", "May 2018", 
"May 2018", "May 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", "May 2020", "May 2020", 
"May 2020", "November 2018", "November 2018", "November 2018", 
"November 2019", "November 2019", "November 2019", "November 2020", 
"November 2020", "November 2020", "October 2018", "October 2018", 
"October 2018", "October 2019", "October 2019", "October 2019", 
"October 2020", "October 2020", "October 2020", "September 2018", 
"September 2018", "September 2018", "September 2019", "September 2019", 
"September 2019", "September 2020", "September 2020", "September 2020"
), Category = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), .rows = structure(list(
    10L, 11L, 12L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    58L, 59L, 60L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
    106L, 107L, 108L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    55L, 56L, 57L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
    88L, 89L, 90L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
    67L, 68L, 69L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 64L, 65L, 
    66L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 97L, 
    98L, 99L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -108L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Monthly boxplot:

```
#convert data into Time series
TS.A <- ts(df.A$Sales, frequency = 12, start = c(2018, 1))

boxplot(TS.A~cycle(TS.A))
```

[image]

....................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ggplotly` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
df.A$Time <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', df.A$Time)

p <- ggplot(df.A, aes(x = Time, y = Sales)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(df.A$Time))
ggplotly(p) %>% layout(xaxis = list(tickangle = 90))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: output is totally different, its not correct

Comment: Hi @Aaron, yes because the data you provided is different than you showed in your output. Did you share all your data or a sample?

Comment: it's not different, you can run my code and check.

Comment: @Aaron The issue is that when converting to a `ts` object you did not take care of the `Time` column but instead assign the first 12 values to year 2018, the next 12 to year 2019 and so on. However, according to the `Time` column that is not the case in your data. Hence, when plotting from the `ts` object the output is different from the one by @Quninten as he is using the `Time` column to create the vector of months, i.e. IMHO the code and plot by @Quinten is correct.

Comment: I checked and the first 12 values belong to year 2018, the next 12 to the year 2019 and so on